# "Multiple Forms In Visualforce Page" caught by Checkmarx scanner

Tags: apex, security-review

One of my pages was scanned by Checkmarx and it's returning this flag "Multiple Forms In Visualforce Page"

Indeed in my page I have several form tags like so:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $CurrentPage.parameters.show_custom_1 == '1'}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Custom Action 1" action="{!customAction1}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>



<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!customText1}"/><br />
    <apex:commandButton value="Update customText1" action="{!updateCustomText1}"/>
</apex:form>
```

One other interesting thing to note is one of these forms is conditional and may or may not appear.

But regardless, it doesn't seem like it should matter? Why is it a problem to have more than one form on a page? That's a very common thing in a modern webpage. I've seen some pages that have 10 forms or more, as long as they are contained to their own area and don't overlap, I don't see why it's a problem?

Comment: I made an assumption that ages ago salesforce didnt work as expected with multiple forms on pages, and that scanner issue may be legacy. I have seen some over release notes that those were fixed in salesforce, but still trying to avoid using multiple forms on page. "Just in case..."

Comment: Will this prevent me from passing security review?

Comment: @user1813867 Does it affect the security review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, see this [blog post](https://th3silverlining.com/2009/10/19/multiple-forms-in-a-single-visualforce-page/), which claims second hand:

> multiple forms cause multiple instances of viewstate on your page, which makes you much more likely to hit the viewstate limit.

I'll see if I can verify that claim. Also note this quote from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_form.htm) on `<apex:form>`:

> It's a best practice to use only one `<apex:form>` tag in a page or custom component.

---

You don't need to wrap each button with a form, they just need to be inside one at some level.

**Multiple Forms**

```
<apex:repeat ...>
    <apex:form><apex:commandButton ... /></apex:form>
</apex:repeat>
```

**One Form**

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:repeat ...>
        <apex:commandButton ... />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I could probably fix this if I could find another way to use a command button without the requirement of the form. Do you know of an alternate way to have a button kick off a controller action? Currently I'm doing this: <apex:form >
                                    <apex:commandButton value="customAction" action="{!customAction}"/>
                                </apex:form>

Comment: Adrian's point is asking why do you need multiple forms. Why is it not possible to have just one form tag at the beginning and end of the page?

Comment: @Adrain Does having multiple form in the VF page affects the security review?