# Command button action without a form?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to remove an apex form object from my visualforce page. All it does is wrap a commandButton like so:

```
<apex:form > <apex:commandButton value="customAction" action="{!customAction}"/> </apex:form>
```

Is there an alternate way to have a button that fires a controller action?

Comment: This is just the same question as [this one](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132700/multiple-forms-in-visualforce-page-caught-by-checkmarx-scanner/132704?noredirect=1#comment188972_132704), no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think he wants to remove form from the page but wants to have command button

Comment: No...read both questions. It's about loops.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes you are correct, kind of duplicate questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to use the `<apex:commandButton>` tag in a loop without including multiple `<apex:form>` tags, simply move the `<apex:form>` tag outside the loop.

**Not So Good**

```
<apex:repeat ...>
    <apex:form><apex:commandButton ... /></apex:form>
</apex:repeat>
```

**A-Okay**

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:repeat ...>
        <apex:commandButton ... />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce standard [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm),

> An `<apex:commandButton>`  component must always be a child of
>   an `<apex:form>`component.

Other option to call server side action is using [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) on button click. But action function also requires apex form.

So you cannot remove apex form from the page if you want to do server side action.